# Allow add to cart for specific products based on cart total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In woocommerce, I am trying to find a way to only allow a product to be added a to cart only when a specific cart total amount is reached.

**Example:**  We want to sell a bumper sticker for **$1**, but only if a user already has **$25** worth of other products already in the cart. This is similar to Amazon's "add on" feature. However I can't find a similar WooCommerce plugin or function.

I have tried yet some code without success… Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be done with a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter hook, where you will define:

- a product Id (or multiple product Ids).
- the threshold cart amount to be reached.

It will avoid for those defined products to be added to cart (displaying a custom notice) until that specific cart amount is reached.

The code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'wc_add_on_feature', 20, 3 );
function wc_add_on_feature( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ) {

    // HERE define one or many products IDs in this array
    $products_ids = array( 37, 27 );

    // HERE define the minimal cart amount that need to be reached
    $amount_threshold = 25;

    // Total amount of items in the cart after discounts
    $cart_amount = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    // The condition
    if( $cart_amount < $amount_threshold && in_array( $product_id, $products_ids ) ){
        $passed = false;
        $text_notice = __( "Cart amount need to be up to $25 in order to add this product", "woocommerce" );
        wc_add_notice( $text_notice, 'error' );
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme).*

Tested and works.